# Windows store supported languages

Tags: windows-store-apps

there,

I hope I choosed the right Forum category...

I've uploaded a windows 10 app to the windows store. I've seen that under supported languages is just german, but in my Package.appxmanifest I have

```
<Resources>
<Resource Language="de-DE" />
<Resource Language="en-US" />
</Resources>
```

In the Partner-Dashboard I have also german and english in my store entrys..

Thanks for your help!

Chris

Answer (score 1):

The **Store listing** on dashboard contains two language lists: **Languages supported by your packages** and **Additional Store listing Languages**.The **Language supported** list of the app in the Store is the same as the **Languages supported by your packages** list in dashboard.

The language shown in the **Languages supported by your packages** list is the language your package supported. If your project supports multiple languages,not only will you need to add languages in the `Package.appxmanifest` file (as shown in the code you listed) ,you will also need to add a.resw file for each language in the project.
In your Resource Language list, the first language 'de-DE' is the default language for your project.For more information about this, please see : [App manifest language list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/manage-language-and-region#app-manifest-language-list)

Comment: I have added a resw file for both languages like "Cultures\en-US\en-US.resw" but there is still just german in the >Language supported by your packages< list...

Comment: And by the way, I'm using the desktop bridge, maybe it has something to do with this...

Comment: You could refer to this article to create your resw file :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest#create-a-resources-file-resw-and-put-your-strings-in-it

Answer (score 0):

After several days of trying to solve this problem, with the help of the Unity people I finally found the answer:

Text edit the Package.appxmanifest file and change from

```
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
```

To the languages your game supports.

```
  <Resources>
          <Resource Language="en-us" />
          <Resource Language="fr" />
          <Resource Language="de" />
          <Resource Language="nl" />
          <Resource Language="pt-br" />
          <Resource Language="ja" />
  </Resources>
```

Then edit the vcxproj of your project and before the  add this (using the same language codes from before) :

```
<AppxBundleAutoResourcePackageQualifiers>DXFeatureLevel</AppxBundleAutoResourcePackageQualifiers>
<AppxDefaultResourceQualifiers>Language=EN-US;FR;DE;JA;NL;PT-BR</AppxDefaultResourceQualifiers>
```

Okay, now just generate the build and send it to the store and all the languages your game supports will appear as expected. =)

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/wsa-build-languages-supported-by-your-packages.1176377/